# How to Connect a Form Input To Array with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, php, html

Please someone should help out.
I'm purely a novice on PHP......

I have an HTML form:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Pin" name="Pin">
```

With a list of php variable arrays

```
<?php
$pin = array("111111", "222222", "333333"); 
?>
```

Now my question is:
How can I set the form input to check among the listed variable if the input exists on the array, then it should do an action, else show incorrect input details?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and the error that you are getting

Comment: I would use the `XMLHttpRequest` instead... but: `if(isset($_POST['Pin'])){ $p = $_POST['Pin']; $pin = array("111111", "222222", "333333");  if(in_array($p, $pin)){ /* it's in the array */ } }`.

Comment: Take a look at `in_array()`

Comment: Edit your question to put the code from comments into it. Multi-line is better.